# How Convert date culture VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

How to convert the date format culture:

(# 8/16/2013 #).ToString ("dd-MMM-yy") the result is: "16-Ago-13"

How to convert culture ("en-us")

Comment: What do you mean?  If you're specifying the format string already, then what do you expect the culture to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at your formatting options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Basically, you can call:

```
myobject.ToString("MY_DATE_FORMAT", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, it corrected as follows:


(#8/16/2013#).ToString("dd-MMM-yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Something like this:-

```
if DateTime.TryParseExact(FieldName, _
      "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
      DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then

      FieldName = dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
  End If
```